# Protect javascript code from copying

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

I have some complex Jquery/Javascript code wich i want to protect from reading. Is there a possibility to put the code in a map wich is only acceable for the webserver? So others can view the page with the jquery functionality, but can't read the sourcecode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and for a good reason: users should always have control over what's executed in their user agents. Why don't you just minify and obfuscate the code?

Comment: Obfuscation *DOES NOT* prevent the code from being read.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yes indeed, neither minification does, but it makes it more difficult to be read.

Comment: You missed the point. "So others can view the page with the jquery functionality, ***but can't read the sourcecode***?" - the code can still be read. Both methods can even be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the Javascript is executed in the browser the source can be read.